# Help With Printing a single item from list inside list in python

Tags: python, list

I first create my grid:

```
grid = []
for x in range(1,collength + 1):
    for y in range(1,collength + 1):
        grid.append([x,y,'e'])
```

Then I make que for my grid and I want to manipulate the que based on the 0, 1, and 2 position of the lists inside the lists:

```
floodfillque = []

grid = floodfillque

for each in floodfillque:
    floodfilllist = []
    currentfloodfill = []
    print '::'
    print each[1]
```

But when I try to print each[1] I get the whole list, not just the nth element of the list inside the list

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code you posted does not work at all. It doesn't even print the whole list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have written it, your code iterates over an empty list. I think you mean:

```
for each in grid:
```

or perhaps:

```
floodfillque = grid
```

This code works fine:

```
collength = 3

grid = []
for x in range(1,collength + 1):
    for y in range(1,collength + 1):
        grid.append([x,y,'e'])

for each in grid:
    floodfilllist = []
    currentfloodfill = []
    print '::'
    print each[1]
```

Result:

```
::
1
::
2
::
3
::
1
::
2
::
3
::
1
::
2
::
3
```

Comment: You're right.  I need to switch grid and floodfillque around.